# Django, wsgi, py. what's the difference?

Tags: apache-2.2, python, django

I'm trying to get a django application up and running on my cpanel system.  I've installed mod_wsgi, and am following the guide here:
http://www.nerdydork.com/setting-up-django-on-a-whm-cpanel-vps-liquidweb.html

However, I'm now confused as I don't know what to do next.  The application has .py files, and I am able to run it via this:
python manage.py  runserver 211.144.131.148:8000

However, that's via command line and binds to port 8000. I want to use Apache instead.

The question is, that tutorial doesn't go further into how to get apache to recognize .py files and run the application as I want it.  What do I do next?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `mod_wsgi`, you don't want Apache to recognize your `.py` files.  Confusing, no?  Here, let me explain...

The WSGI module provides an interconnect of sorts between Apache and your Python processes. It's a standardized gateway interface (Web Server Gateway Interface), so to speak.

[Here's the official Django documentation on configuring Django 1.1 with Apache & `mod_wsgi`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/).

Generally, you'll just need:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite/apache/django.wsgi
```

And then you'll need to define a WSGI application, which serves as front to your Django application:

```
import os
import sys

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

*Note that I took these examples from that document linked above.

This now wires up Apache to a WSGI app and then ties your application into that WSGI app. The WSGIScriptAlias line simply tells apache to send all requests at '/' or lower to your WSGI application, which will manage the URL routing.

I usually do deployments like this using FastCGI & the Python flup module, which is a little more complex, but worth checking out if you've the time.

Comment: It is a lot more confusing than that. You can have mod_wsgi recognise .py files in arbitrary directories, but .wsgi is recommended because quite often .py is mapped as a CGI script. There are other reasons to avoid .py extension besides that as well however. Anyway, for different ways to configure mod_wsgi see 'http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide'.